# Why does not this Visual basic code produce any results?

Tags: vb.net, crc32

I am running this code in a Windows Application Form project in visual basic. This code is supposed to give me CRC-32 bytes for an array of bytes, but no matter what I do I can not output any bytes. Sorry if there is something really obvious that I am missing here, but I have already tried "MsgBox",the "immediate screen" with the "debug.print" and I also tried printing the bytes inside a text box, but no results. I appreciate it if you be able to help me with this.

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub Main()

    Dim lCrc32Value As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    lCrc32Value = InitCrc32()
    lCrc32Value = AddCrc32("This is the original message!", _
       lCrc32Value)
    'Debug.Print(Hex$(GetCrc32(lCrc32Value)))

    TextBox1.Text = (Hex$(GetCrc32(lCrc32Value))).ToString
End Sub
'// Then declare this array variable Crc32Table
Private Crc32Table(255) As Long
'// Then all we have to do is write public functions like
'these...
Public Function InitCrc32(Optional ByVal Seed As Long = _
   &HEDB88320, Optional ByVal Precondition As _
   Long = &HFFFFFFFF) As Long

    '// Declare counter variable iBytes, 
    'counter variable iBits, 
    'value variables lCrc32 and lTempCrc32

    Dim iBytes As Integer, iBits As Integer, lCrc32 As Long
    Dim lTempCrc32 As Long

    '// Turn on error trapping
    On Error Resume Next

    '// Iterate 256 times
    For iBytes = 0 To 255

        '// Initiate lCrc32 to counter variable
        lCrc32 = iBytes

        '// Now iterate through each bit in counter byte
        For iBits = 0 To 7
            '// Right shift unsigned long 1 bit
            lTempCrc32 = lCrc32 And &HFFFFFFFE
            lTempCrc32 = lTempCrc32 \ &H2
            lTempCrc32 = lTempCrc32 And &H7FFFFFFF

            '// Now check if temporary is less than zero and then 
            'mix Crc32 checksum with Seed value
            If (lCrc32 And &H1) <> 0 Then
                lCrc32 = lTempCrc32 Xor Seed
            Else
                lCrc32 = lTempCrc32
            End If
        Next

        '// Put Crc32 checksum value in the holding array
        Crc32Table(iBytes) = lCrc32
    Next

    '// After this is done, set function value to the 
    'precondition value
    InitCrc32 = Precondition

End Function

'// The function above is the initializing function, now 
'we have to write the computation function
Public Function AddCrc32(ByVal Item As String, _
  ByVal Crc32 As Long) As Long

    '// Declare following variables
    Dim bCharValue As Byte, iCounter As Integer, lIndex As Long
    Dim lAccValue As Long, lTableValue As Long

    '// Turn on error trapping
    On Error Resume Next

    '// Iterate through the string that is to be checksum-computed
    For iCounter = 1 To Len(Item)

        '// Get ASCII value for the current character
        bCharValue = Asc(Mid$(Item, iCounter, 1))

        '// Right shift an Unsigned Long 8 bits
        lAccValue = Crc32 And &HFFFFFF00
        lAccValue = lAccValue \ &H100
        lAccValue = lAccValue And &HFFFFFF

        '// Now select the right adding value from the 
        'holding table
        lIndex = Crc32 And &HFF
        lIndex = lIndex Xor bCharValue
        lTableValue = Crc32Table(lIndex)

        '// Then mix new Crc32 value with previous 
        'accumulated Crc32 value
        Crc32 = lAccValue Xor lTableValue
    Next

    '// Set function value the the new Crc32 checksum
    AddCrc32 = Crc32

End Function

'// At last, we have to write a function so that we 
'can get the Crc32 checksum value at any time
Public Function GetCrc32(ByVal Crc32 As Long) As Long
    '// Turn on error trapping
    On Error Resume Next

    '// Set function to the current Crc32 value
    GetCrc32 = Crc32 Xor &HFFFFFFFF

End Function
'// And for testing the routines above...



End Class
```

Comment: you should consider switching to SHA256 or maybe even MD5 if performance is important - CRC32 is vastly outdated and doesnt even yield reliable transportation-layer-validity info anymore. You really should use AT LEAST MD5, which is available for everyone to use at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacmd5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: All those On Error Resume Next seems there just to hide errors. And please set OPTION STRICT ON and you discover a lot of errors in your code when converting long to integers

Comment: @Steve: I'd +10 that comment if I could.

Comment: Thanks guys. The reason that I am using CRC-32 is that the device I am trying to communicate with uses CRC-32 and I need to check the received CRC bytes of the received array with the ones I am trying to calculate for the array of bytes. As for OPTION STRICT ON, I turned it on and did not notice any particular error messages regarding those errors that you mentioned. Guys I really appreciate it if you guide me to a functioning CRC-32 code, because I have tried a few and failed to get any output so far.

Comment: You probably want the code you've put in `Sub Main` in `Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load` instead. Delete all those `On Error Resume Next` lines as they do nothing useful. And you can use the [>> Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83.aspx) to right-shift an integral value.

Comment: +1 on everything @AndrewMorton said, except using Form Load.  Exceptions may not be properly caught there and you could have some of them as you proceed.  use a button click.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.  First, all the CRC code should be in a Class not intermingled with the form. Second, Option Strict is not on as there are several implicit conversions which  will likley break the result:

```
' converting Integer to Byte
bCharValue = Asc(Mid$(Item, iCounter, 1))

' see note 7
DIm lIndex As Long
' converting integer to Long
lIndex = Crc32 And &HFF

' here too:
lTableValue = Crc32Table(lIndex)
```

#3. Get rid of the `On Error Resume next`.  that is not error handling - it HIDES errors from you.

#4. You never call the Main function.  **Do Not Call It from Form Load** debugging will be too difficult from there. Add a button and call Main from the click event.

#5. Strongly advise migrating from the old VB function to their equivalents in NET which are much more robust.

#6. Changes to AddCRC32:

---

```
Public Function AddCrc32(ByVal Item As String, ByVal Crc32 As Long) As Long
    '// Declare following variables
    Dim bCharValue As Byte, iCounter As Integer, lIndex As Long
    Dim lAccValue As Long, lTableValue As Long

    ' convert text to char array all at once
    Dim strChars = Item.ToCharArray

    '// Iterate through the string that is to be checksum-computed
    For iCounter = 0 To Item.Length - 1

        '// Get ASCII value for the current character
        'bCharValue = Asc(Mid$(Item, iCounter, 1))

        ' NET version
        bCharValue = Convert.ToByte(strChars(iCounter))

        '// Right shift an Unsigned Long 8 bits
        lAccValue = Crc32 And &HFFFFFF00
        lAccValue = lAccValue \ &H100
        lAccValue = lAccValue And &HFFFFFF

        '// Now select the right adding value from the 
        'holding table
        lIndex = Crc32 And &HFF
        lIndex = lIndex Xor bCharValue
        lTableValue = Crc32Table(CInt(lIndex))

        '// Then mix new Crc32 value with previous 
        'accumulated Crc32 value
        Crc32 = lAccValue Xor lTableValue
    Next

    '// Set function value the the new Crc32 checksum
    ' a REALLY big indicator that this came from VB6:
    AddCrc32 = Crc32

    ' NET is usually:
    ' Return Crc32

End Function
```

#7:  The lIndex fix above *should* be right from what I recall of CRC32.  The alternative is the reverse: Change it to Integer and convert `Crc32 And &HFF` to integer.

Note, I did not check any of the CRC32 stuff (like table initializer), just the OPTION Strict issues and hooking it up, and check for initial exceptions.

---

Addendum

I found my own old CRC32 code and when comparing, I found some CRC related issues:

Almost everything in your `Buildtable/InitCrc32` procedure, including the return should be Integer (Int32) not long (Int64).  It looks like you copied code from a VB6 source and it is not properly updated (should not need `Long` anywhere for this).

For text encoding, you probably want this:

```
Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
Dim byt As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(s)
```

rather than the `Convert.ToByte` given above.  As I said, I mainly looked at getting it working in some form or fashion, not certifying the algorithm.

Comment: I'd use `Return value` rather than `FunctionName = value`. And some of the comments in the original seem misleading, e.g. `'// Right shift an Unsigned Long 8 bits` looks like it should be `' Right shift by 8 bits and truncate`. Good point about code in Form_Load being difficult to debug. Your lIndex fix gives the same result as the OP's code.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  yes, the old style `Returns` and comments are other indicators the source is some old VB6 code converted; there is also too much use of Long (Int64) for computing a CRC32 in NET. I didnt tinker with his algorithm at all lest it all come unraveled, just fixed the `Option Strict` issues and get it to fire. Looking at the CRC stuff now though.

Comment: System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes is a public shared function.. and I prefer FunctionName = value .. certainly with boolean returning functions

Comment: [Public Overridable Function GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah.. what I mean is System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 is a public shared readonly property.. System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s) or System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s) will suffice

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I apologize for coming back to you so late as I have been very sick recently.